# Is it possible to dynamically set notify_url for recurring payments in PayPal?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-subscriptions

I've run into a slight predicament in regards to the PayPal IPN system. My client already has an IPN URL designated for their store, however I am building a custom application which presents the ability to subscribe to a service. I need to be able to receive IPN notifications, however I've seen varying answers in regards to whether or not you can dynamically set the notification URL for recurring payments through the `notify_url` parameter.

Has anyone recently dealt with this situation? I'm aware that it's possible to setup a handler that will pass requests to various IPN handlers however the store system that my client requires the request to be sent directly from PayPal, third-party vendors' requests are ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `notify_url` as a parameter of the form that is submitted when the button is clicked, and that will override whatever notification URL is set on the account.

However AFAIK you can't change it again subsequently.